# Error, while adding authentication providers to Firebase_ui_auth package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase_ui_auth as user authentication in a Flutter app. When implementing providers, according to the [GitHub instructions][1], I get this error `The argument type 'List<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>>?`

When I use only `var providers = [EmailAuthProvider()]`, it goes fine but when I add `var providers = [EmailAuthProvider(), GoogleAuthProvider()]`, it throws the error.

Documentation from GitHub repository (by Firebase) says that I can add more providers to the providers list as screenshot below.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Please, how do I solve this?

My `main.dart` code below

````
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseUIAuth.configureProviders([
    EmailAuthProvider(),
    GoogleAuthProvider() //<-Error here when added GoogleAuthProvider()
  ]);
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My Cool App',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.indigo),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      home: const AuthGate(),
      builder: EasyLoading.init(),
    );
  }
}

class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var providers = [EmailAuthProvider(), GoogleAuthProvider()]; //<-Error here when added GoogleAuthProvider()
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return const MyHomePage();
        } else {
          return SignInScreen(
            providers: providers,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}```

Seems like the link and image aren't displaying well.

  [1]: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_ui_auth/doc/providers/email.md
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlOTQ.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is mixed up with the previous deprecated package [FlutterFire UI](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_ui). When you use [Firebase UI Auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_auth), you need to use firebase_ui_oauth_XXXX package. So, for google sign in, you need to add [Firebase UI OAuth Google](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_oauth_google) package.

Your code should be adjusted as below.

```
FirebaseUIAuth.configureProviders([
EmailAuthProvider(),
GoogleProvider(),]);
```

P.S. Both `firebase_auth` and `firebase_ui_auth` package have EmailAuthProvider methods. So, make sure you import `firebase_auth` as below when both of these packages are imported together.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide EmailAuthProvider;
```

Comment: I have the same error and this does not fix it for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID' to GoogleProvider.

`GoogleProvider(clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)`

More info here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Flutter/blob/main/docs/firebase-ui-auth/providers/oauth.md#google-sign-in

Answer (score -1):

First check your imports, make sure to have the "**hide**" part:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide EmailAuthProvider;
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_google/firebase_ui_oauth_google.dart';
```

Then build the providers like this:

```
providers: [
             EmailAuthProvider(),
             GoogleProvider(clientId: "YOUR_WEBCLIENT_ID"),  // new
           ],
```

For the full source see this official guide:
https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps#6